# Spark configuration priority

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Does there any difference or priority between specifying spark application configuration in the code :

```
SparkConf().setMaster(yarn)
```

and specifying them in command line

```
spark-submit --master yarn
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, the highest priority is given to the configuration in the user's code with the set() function. After that there the flags passed with spark-submit.

> Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.

[Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: can the properties be changed dynamically while application is running?

Comment: @VeeraMarni it depends on the property. For example, you can dynamically change `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` between jobs of a same Spark application, but not `spark.executor.memory` nor `spark.driver.cores` etc... Sadly I don't know where you can find an exhaustive list of non dynamic configurations, I would also be interested in finding one !

Comment: @EnzoBnl Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There are 4 precedence level: (1 to 4 , 1 being the highest priority):

1. SparkConf set in the application
2. Properties given with the spark-submit
3. Properties can be given in a property file. And the
   property file can be given as argument while submission
4. Default values

Answer (score 3):

Other than the priority, specifying it on a command-line would allow you to run on different cluster managers without modifying code. The same application can be run on local[n] or yarn or mesos or spark standalone cluster.