# Set spark context configuration prioritizing spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I'm building a dockerized spark application, which will be run through an `entrypoint.sh` file which in turn runs a `spark-submit`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath):$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/*
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=8g"

spark-submit \
    --master local \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///job/log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///job/log4j.properties"\
    --files "/job/log4j.properties" \
     main.py --train_path $1 --test_path $2
```

As you can see, I'm setting part of the configuration via the `spark-submit` `--conf`options.

If in the `spark-submit` statement I set a configuration parameter which will also be set in `main.py` via:

```
SparkConf().set(option, value)
```

`set` has priority over `spark-submit`, and hence for whatever configuration is set in both ways, only what is set using `SparkConf().set` will prevail  ([see other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885680/spark-configuration-priority#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20the%20highest%20priority%20is,conf%20file)).

What I've been trying to achieve is to be able to control the spark configuration **prioritizing what is set in `spark-submit`**. There seems to be the parameter [`SparkConf.setIfMissing`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkConf.setIfMissing.html), but I'm not sure I'm using it properly.

What I've tried is to instanciate a `SparkConf()` object and set the configuration using the aforementioned method, as: `SparkConf().setIfMissing(option, value)`. But it's not working. It overrides whatever is set in `spark-submit`. My guess is that until the context is not initialized, you can't retrieve what has been set via `spark-submit`.

So I'm unsure how to use `SparkConf.setIfMissing` for this case, if this is it's purpose to begin with? Otherwise, is there some other approach to accomplish this behaviour? Would appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Stopping the `SparkContext` and retrieving all parameters set via `spark-submit`, and *then* creating a new context did it. The steps would be as follows:

- Initialize `SparkContext`
- Retrieve all previously set configuration via `sc.getConf()` and stop the previous context using `sc.stop()`
- Set all remaining configuration using `SparkConf().setIfMissing()` and create a new context with the new configuration `SparkContext(conf=conf)`

The last step enables to prioritize the configuration set via `spark-submit`. That way, only parameters that have not been previously set are set through this method.
In code, that would be:

```
config = my_config_dict
sc = SparkContext()
sc.stop()
conf = sc.getConf()
for option in my_config_dict.keys():
    conf.setIfMissing(option, my_config_dict[option])
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```